# Examples of PHP In C++

Tags: php, c++

Well I want to learn C++ and at the moment I'm only familiar with PHP and Javascript. And I thought a good way to start learning would be to transfer methods in PHP to C++.

So basically I want the code snippets below in C++

The post with the best comments will get a big green tick.

Also, if you know of a good beginners tutorial please leave a comment.

So here are the bits of code I want in C++

**First**

```
$array = array('I\'m', 'learning', 'C++');
foreach($array as $word){
    echo $word.' ';
}
```

**Second**

```
function foo($num,$ber, $add = true){
    if(is_numeric($num) && is_numeric($ber)){
        if(!$add){
            echo $num*$ber;
        }
        else{
            echo $num + $ber;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'They aren\'t numbers!';
    }
}
foo(2,4, false);
```

Comment: May I offer a better PHP for those PHP snippets? :) 1st: echo implode(' ', $array) . ' '; 2nd: boolean argument in a function means it must be 2 functions. The code in the 2nd case looks _very_ artificial. Wouldn't write anything like this for production. But for sake of understanding C++, well... if it would help you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*never* try to learn any complex subject by 'translating' from another one, no matter how well you know the old one.

You'd only get inconsistent concepts, with the limitations of both and the advantages of none.

Answer (score 13):

I'm skeptical about the pedagogical usefulness of translating this into C++. Just translating the above code may not be too useful.  Take your first example, where you loop over an array of strings and print out each word - sure, I could translate this into C++ using an `std::vector<std::string>`, iterate over the vector and output each string to stdout.  But is that really going to teach you anything?  I could also use a C array of `const char*` pointers, iterate over that and call `printf` on each one.  But is that really going to teach you anything?

Since you already know how to code in PHP and Javascript, you're obviously aware of basic programming concepts like variables, loops, conditionals, etc.  But C++ is a *dramatically* different language than either PHP or Javascript.  For one thing, it's statically typed.  For another thing, it requires manual memory management.  So I think rather than trying to translate PHP code to C++, you'd be better off reading a [good introductory book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139798099) to C++.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'd be much better off if you tried to figure it out and asked questions you had about it along the way.